# I have issues to create a second jar artifact with Maven jar plugin

Tags: maven, jar

I am unable to add a second jar as whenever I use the maven jar plugin the jar that would be created by default is not created.

Does anyone know the meaning of "the jar-plugin must be defined in a new execution" in this [maven page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html). This seems very related.

Comment: Why do you need a second jar ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to repackage it differently

Answer (score 0):

Just add another one `<execution>` section in your pom.xml for the artifact (namely, jar) that you want to create. It will look something like this:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>jar</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <!-- your configuration for the 2nd jar -->
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

The default jar would still be built along with your custom configured jar, at least it seems so from the documentation, please let me know if it doesn't.

Also consider creating 2 sub-projects, one for each artifact and separating your code into different packages. That's usually the case when you need 2 jars, not one. There's more information given in this sonatype [blog post](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

Comment: That's just it. I do not have any <execution> section in my Pom. It would be easy to understand if I did. I do not know how to create a NEW execution section as the maven page refers.

Comment: well, what do you have ?

Comment: you must have maven-jar-plugin, then add 2 executions to it

Comment: If I add two executions then I am replacing the execution that would have been attached to the package phase with the two new execution I am adding.  This is not what the documented page states.  It says I should add a new one so as not to override the default one.  This is what I do not know how to do.

Comment: Also, how do I know what the default execution looked like since in your suggestion I would have to rewrite it?  This is precisely what the comment in the documentation seem to solve it just does not tell us how to.

Comment: default execution is omitted (but I haven't seen your pom so can't tell for sure), but you can have it with `<execution><id>default-jar</id><phase>package</phase></execution>`, then add configuration for 2nd execution

Comment: please also make sure you know about maven assembly plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I understand everything you say however this does explain the wording on the maven page. Is it that what you describe is what is meant? If so it is very misleading and should be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about assembly. Will look into it.

Comment: yeah, I think that's what was meant, see also sonatype blog http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/ (it mentions that there should be only one execution, as the default one is always executed if not overriden, so I was partially correct).